# makeKeyAndVisible changes orientation of view iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

In method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate I initiate a view controller and add to navigation view controller that becomes window root view controller.
Because my iPad app is only horizontal orientation all my view controllers are made for landscape.

Here is the code:

```
self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
self.myNavigationController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.myViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.myNavigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

When I put breakpoint on "self.window.rootViewController = self.myNavigationController;" line and call in console to display view details, I get following:
$0 = 0x0c89d010 >

which I read the rect is orientation mode (1024 width and 748 height)

The next breakpoint that is on "return YES;" shows me this:
$1 = 0x0c89d010 >

<strike>which copy an object (as far as I can see) and</strike> changes orientation (768 width and 1004 height)

This only happens in iOS5, however iOS6 works as expected

Is there any known issue with MakeKeyAndVisible method that I should know?
Or may be it is lack of my understanding how makeKeyAndVisible works

Comment: are you implementing the orientation methods for iOS5?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `makeKeyAndVisible` - the way orientation is handled was changed between iOS 5 and iOS 6

Comment: I am implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method in my view controller to make sure it is landscape.

Comment: You need to implement custom NavigationController, with the usage of navigationcontroller all your orientation methods would be disturbed.

Comment: Sorry, message was trimmed: I got this in console (respectively) UIView: 0xc89d010; frame = (0 0; 1024 748); autoresize = W+H; layer and UIView: 0x9b92850; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; layer

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and does this method get called?

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
} This method gets called as I put breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom UINavigationController with all the orientation methods inside it and use it in your app.

It would be something like this

**CustomNavigationController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.m**

```
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"


@interface CustomNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationController


//overriding shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method for working in navController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return   [self.topViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation];

}

//other methods
```

This way your orientations would be working accordingly in your corresponding viewCotrollers.

Comment: This potentially looks like overkill

Comment: This is how I have solved problems with orientation in my apps while using navigationController.

Comment: It's been a while since I got mixed up with it but I thought that `UINavigationController` defaulted to using the viewController's `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` anyway

Comment: Because viewController is pushed via navigationcontroller this way orientations would not act normally but implementing custom navigation controller would let the viewcontroller's orientation methods to work properly.

Comment: I have already implemented custom navigation controller : MyNavigationController and orientation is set to landscape

Comment: First set the orientations which you are supporting in your project target settings or try implementing this method in your appDelegate `- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window`

Comment: the problem is that if I reuse self.myViewController after makeKeyAndVisible was called, and rely on rect from self.myViewController it provides portrait rect orientation, only for the first time the app was called. Every time after the applicationDidBecomeActive is called self.myViewController rect is in correct (landscape) orientation. That's why it would be more crucial to understand what makeKeyAndVisible really does

Comment: If you are supporting only landscape orientation in your project settings and in orientation methods then it should show landscape.

Comment: After calling the makeKeyAndVisible, try pushing your first view controller on navigationController, it would solve your problem

Comment: Pushing after makeKeyAndVisible it resolves the problem partially and I don't think it is a good fix. I will investigate the problem more in depth, especially want to find out what exactly makeKeyAndVisible does. One correction to above posts - actually the object stays the same, it does not copy after calling makeKeyAndVisible. That was my careless investigation. It actually only changes the rect of the view controller as stated above - corrected

Comment: well if you read the [apple docs for UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) then you can find what is it all about